# Updating a part of string in column MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am looking for smart idea to update just a part of string in column. There is lot of similar question but I haven't found way for me.

For example I have column `varchar(10)`

```
1234|5|6789X
____________
2134|1|71891
```

How I can easy update 5th element of my string without touching rest of string, there is no pattern.

I was trying use `patindex` & `substring`

Comment: Show us your tries with pathindex and substring

Comment: Do pipes occures always??

Comment: `How I can easy update 5th element of my string` what is the 5th element? Can you show what you have tried and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

`STUFF(Column_Name,Char_Index_Start_Position,Lenght_to_Replace,Replaced_string)`

for your case try

```
STUFF(column_name,5,1,'1')
```

**[STUFF()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

How about [*Stuff*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

```
SELECT Stuff('1234|5|6789X', 6, 1, '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your column is `varchar(10)`, I assume that in the data you have give us in question

```
1234|5|6789X
____________
2134|1|71891
```

`|5|` and `|1|` need to be replaced.

As many have pointed out already, you can use `STUFF`

However correct way to implement it would be

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN (col) >4 THEN STUFF(col,5,1,'X')
ELSE col END FROM tbl
```

where `tbl` is your table name and `col` is your column name and replace `'X'` with what you want as replacement.

**Explanation:** Reason for using `CASE` is because if `STUFF` encounters a string which does not have 5th character in above statement then it returns `NULL`.